# Hadoop wordcount Pseudodistributed mode error Exit code:127

Tags: java, xml, hadoop

I have installed Hadoop 2.7.1 stable version. I followed Tom White's book for installation in Pseudodistributed mode. I did set all environment variables like JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, PATH etc.. I configured yarn-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml.

I copied the sample file file.txt using following command.

```
$hadoop fs -copyFromLocal textFiles/file.txt file.txt
```

which shows me

```
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 RAMA supergroup       3737 2015-12-27 21:52 file.txt
drwxr-xr-x   - RAMA supergroup          0 2015-12-27 22:17 input
```

When I am executing the wordcount program in hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar using below command

```
RAMAs-MacBook-Pro:hadoop-2.7.1 RAMA$ hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar wordcount file.txt output
```

it is throwing me following exception, for which I am not able to find any feasible solution.

```
15/12/27 22:41:52 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/12/27 22:41:53 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8032
15/12/27 22:41:53 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/12/27 22:41:53 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/12/27 22:41:53 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1451216397139_0020
15/12/27 22:41:54 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1451216397139_0020
15/12/27 22:41:54 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://192.168.1.6:8088/proxy/application_1451216397139_0020/
15/12/27 22:41:54 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1451216397139_0020
15/12/27 22:41:57 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1451216397139_0020 running in uber mode : false
15/12/27 22:41:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/12/27 22:41:57 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1451216397139_0020 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1451216397139_0020 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1451216397139_0020_000002 exited with  exitCode: 127
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://192.168.1.6:8088/cluster/app/application_1451216397139_0020Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1451216397139_0020_02_000001
Exit code: 127
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=127: 
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
15/12/27 22:41:57 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

Any suggestions/comments is of great help...

Comment: You need to look at the task level logs.

Comment: Open http://192.168.1.6:8088/cluster/app/application_1451216397139_0020 and check what does it says?

Comment: Thnx Durga and Jack for your suggestions. After I checked task level logs, I came to know that /bin/java does not exist. I have done changes as mentioned in https://cloudcelebrity.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/yarn-job-problem-application-application_-failed-1-times-due-to-am-container-for-xx-exited-with-exitcode-127/. However, I had to do that change after going rootless.. After changing "sudo ln -s /usr/bin/java /bin/java", I was able to execute the map-reduce program.

Answer (score 1):

In hadoop-env.sh, explicitly add the java home path in JAVA_HOME variable.